# Objects in random places after exporting?

Tags: export, unity

I have created previous models of human organ models using Blender, which then are exported to Abaqus and Unity in order to be included in biomechanical studies, and everything went fine.

However, I am now trying to create new models for new structures, and I am using the exact same method as before and the same source for the models, but the new objects are in a completely different position and rotation as the ones already created and treated after many hours of work...

I have tried many approaches to solve this problem, and none of them worked. I do not want to lose every hour of work already spent, so how can I maintain the new organs in the positions they were before?

[EDIT]: My blender file for one example is on the provided link, and it's possible to see that the ureters are out of place, when compared with the bladder/prostate/urethra, even though they were captured from the same view, position and time, from an executable human atlas. In the pictures (the second link provided) the ureters are the objects which are highlighted, and it's possible to see that they are dislocated from the rest, even when the same transforms are applied. The second screenshot shows the export settings, and I have confirmed they are correct. Sometimes, the objects appear in a completly different position (in this case they are kind of aligned).

Blender file: [image]

Screenshots:

[image: text]

[image: text]

Comment: Can you edit and post some images to clarify the problem?

Comment: I doubt very much they are _"random"_   Blender uses Z axis up Y forward, other engines use Y up.  Make sure the correct setting to import / export is set.  Often searching for blender import export on forum(s) is fruitful..

Comment: * other engines' forums

Comment: Consider sharing example files (old-good and new-bad) (upload it to blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com then paste the provided link, editing your question) as it would make your issue much more clear...

Comment: I have edited my question, which now has the file with an example of the problem I am having and with some screenshots